# Dojo 1.9.3 xhr vs iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, dojo, xmlhttprequest

What to use really?! I have a request/xhr module which cannot post a multipart/form-data (Two text fields and a file upload). When using Iframe I can post the form with no problem. I would like to use xhr though. Iframe on the other hand cannot be used because I won't be able to read the response body. Does xhr support multipart/for-data? Is there another alternative to perform this simple task: post a file and two names and get a JSONObject response. I'm reading the file in parts.

```
    ***************************  Dojo Code ***************************

 <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
  <script src='dojo-release-1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
 </head>

 <body class="claro">
 <form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="myForm" data-dojo-id="myForm"
   encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method="">
   <label for="firstname">FirstName</label><input data-dojo-  
   type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" type="text" name="fname"/>
   <label for="lastname">LastName:</label><input data-dojo-
   type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" type="text" name="lname" />
 <label for="fileName">Certificate Upload:</label><input type="file" name="fileName" />
    <button type="button" id="startButton">Start</button> </form>

 <script>
 require(["dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-form", "dojo/dom-construct", 
 "dojo/json", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
  function(xhr, dom, domForm, domConst, JSON, on){

  on(dom.byId("startButton"), "click", function(){
  var data = domForm.toObject("myForm");

  xhr("addUser",{
  data: data,
  method:"post",
   handleAs:"json"
   }).then(function(cert){    
    alert("data received!");       
   }, function(err){    
   alert("data denied!!!");    
   alert(err); }); }); });
```

*************************   Servlet Code ****************************

```
       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  

    String FirstName = request.getParameter("fname"); // Retrieves <input type="text"  
    name="description">
    String LastName = request.getParameter("lname"); // Retrieves <input type="text" 
    name="description">
    Part Certfile = request.getPart("fileName"); // Retrieves <input type="file" 
    name="file">
    String Certname = getFilename(Certfile); // Calls getFilename method

    InputStream Certcontent = Certfile.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Certcontent));
```

Comment: While everything is going well with iframe. Unfortunately i can't read the body of response.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a good work around since nobody seemed to know the solution to this.

**Task:** Needed to post a form to a 3.0 servlet using multipart/form-data that had text fields and a file all within the AJAX method.

Dojo request methods fell short on most mehtods and sometimes couldn't work with AJAX. They would require a new page.

**Solution:** I added in an iframe tag and changed the form to target the iframe. **SOLVED!**

```
  <iframe id="uploadTrg" name="uploadTrg" height="0" width="0"></iframe>
```

Now Ajax and form with text and file are working.